# shape disappearing when adding tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
 \tikzset{
    rect/.style={
        font=\small,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=1em,
    text width=2em,
    %draw=blue!75,                                                                                                                                                                                     
    very thick,
    align=center,
    }%                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }%                                                                                                                                                                                                     
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [draw=black] (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);                                                                                                                                                     
  %\tikz\draw[rect] (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
  \node[single arrow, draw=blue,
    minimum width = 1.0cm, single arrow head extend=1cm,
    minimum height = 2cm] at (2.0, 2.0)[anchor = center] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

However, when I comment

```
  \draw [draw=black] (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
```

and uncomment

```
  %\tikz\draw[rect] (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
```

the shape of the fat arrow disappears:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Try to remove the `\tikz` in `\tikz\draw[rect] (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
`.

Comment: Command `\tikz` is equivalent to `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`, so you were nesting `tikzpictures` which is something to avoid.

Comment: @JuanCastaño, removing `\tikz` works.

Comment: @JuanCastaño Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, done :D

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the comments, is a bad idea include `\tikz` inside a `tikzpicture` environment. You are nesting `tikzpictures` and that is bound to produce errors. So just remove the `\tikz` command and you'll have it.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
 \tikzset{
    rect/.style={
    font=\small,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=1em,
    text width=2em,
    %draw=blue!75,                                           
    very thick,
    align=center,
    }%                                           
    }%
                                                              
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % \draw [draw=black] (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
  \draw[rect] (0.0, 0.0) rectangle (4.0, 4.0);
  \node[single arrow, draw=blue,
    minimum width  = 1.0cm, single arrow head extend=1cm,
    minimum height = 2cm] at (2.0, 2.0)[anchor = center] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mostly off-topic (your problem is solved by @Juan Castaño answer, +1) ...

It is a bit unusual that for drawing rectangle path is used style, which is normally use for nodes. So, I see two possible ways to draw your picture:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                shapes.arrows}

 \tikzset{
   rect/.style = {rounded corners, very thick},
     SA/.style = {single arrow, draw=blue, thin, sharp corners,
                  minimum width=1.0cm, minimum height = 2cm,
                  single arrow head extend=1cm},
%%
    FIT/.style = {draw, rounded corners, very thick, inner sep=1cm,
                  fit=#1},
        } 

\begin{document}
% draw rectangle    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rect] (0,0) rectangle (4, 4) node[SA, midway] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

or 
 
% use of nodes
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[SA] (n1)  {};
\node[FIT=(n1)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]